# Compass Not Creating CSS Files

Tags: ruby, sass, compass

When I run `compass compile`, the operation runs successfully, but no CSS files are created in my CSS directory. This is my folder structure:

```
css
images
src
 -config.rb
 -screen.scss
 -overrides.css
```

And my `config.rb` file:

```
http_path = "./"
css_dir = "../css"
sass_dir = "./"
images_dir = "../images"
javascripts_dir = "../javascripts"
line_comments = false
```

- compass v1.1.0.alpha.3
- sass v3.4.22
- sass-rails v5.0.4
- ruby v2.1.1p76

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem should be with the directories you've specified for your assets i.e `css_dir`, `sass_dir`, `images_dir` and `javascripts_dir`

The values for the directories are all *relative* to the `http-path`.

With the current value for the `css_dir` in your code, Compass should be generating the `css` outside your project folder.
You paths should look more like

```
http_path = '/'
css_dir = 'css'
sass_dir = 'sass' // I suggest you create a folder for all your sass files
images_dir = 'images'
javascripts_dir = 'javascripts'
```